# When we try to separate style files app doesn't render it shows spinner with background all time

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo, native-base

[image of CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsKwA.jpg)
Before doing it styles were on the same files. We cut all styles and pasted it on the separate file. Here is how it looks like.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Dimensions} from "react-native";
const win = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles={
  content: {

  justifyContent:'center'
},

  img: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    width: win.width,
         height: win.height,

  },


  item:{
borderBottomColor: "#0dc49c"
  },

  icon:{
color: "#a4916c",
 marginLeft: 10,
  marginRight: 5
  },

  input:{
    color: "#a4916c"
  },

  list:{
     borderBottomWidth: 0,
     borderTopWidth: 0,
     borderBottomColor: "#a4916c",
  },

  contacticon: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontSize: 60,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#0dc49c",
    marginBottom: 2,
  },
  contacttext: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontSize: 25,
    color: "#0dc49c",
    marginBottom: 180,
  },

}

module.exports = styles;
```

When it was on the same files as components it was worked perfectly while because of duplicate styles we decided to separate them. What is wrong? How can it be fixed?

Comment: How do you import it in your component ?

Comment: import {styles} from "../styles/file";

<Item style={styles.item} >   looks like this for each element.  Also I haven't added 'use strict' hope it is not a reason for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using styles like this

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 content: {
   justifyContent:'center'
 },
});

module.exports = styles;
```

and import styles like this

```
import styles from "../styles/file
```